# findOneAndUpdate entry if it is the oldest/youngest entry in collection and passes filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i've been looking around stackoverflow and could only find 1 unanswered similar question.

how do i get the oldest/youngest entry in my collection and only update it, if the var "state" in the document equals "one".

its important that findOneAndUpdate is used to make it atomic.

this is what my code looks like, but it only gets the oldest entry after filtering, which isn't necesarilly the oldest entry. its important that the code never updates a document which isn't the oldest and/or doesn't pass the filter.

```
  MongoClient.connect(uri, function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("my-db");
  let query = { state: "one" };
  var newvalues = { $set: { state: "two" } };
  dbo
    .collection("my-collection")
    .findOneAndUpdate(query, newvalues)
    .sort({ dateTime: 1 }, function (err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      db.close();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your collection/document model, here's one way using an aggregation pipeline with `"$merge"` to update the oldest document where `"state": "one"` to `"state": "two"`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "state": "one"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "datetime": 1
    }
  },
  { "$limit": 1 },
  {
    "$set": {
      "state": "two"
    }
  },
  { "$merge": "collection" }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kjtyuQB-SIR).